# C# How convert unHex to String

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert an unHex value to a string but it's not working.

I have the following value `0x01BB92E7F716F55B144768FCB2EA40187AE6CF6B2E52A64F7331D0539507441F7D770112510D679F0B310116B0D709E049A19467672FFA532A7C30DFB72`

Result I hope would be this

[image]

but executing the function below displays this result

`»’ Ç ÷ õ [Ghü²ê @ zæÏk.R¦Os1ÐS • D} w Q gŸ 1 ° × àI¡ ”gg / úS * | 0ß ·) = ¤`

Any idea how I can extract the information as expected

```
public static string Hex2String (string input)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder ();
    for (int i = 0; i < socketLength; i + = 2)
    {
        // throws an exception if not properly formatted
        string hexdec = input.Substring (i, 2);
        int number = Int32.Parse (hexdec, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        char charToAdd = (char) number;
        builder.Append (charToAdd);
    }
    return builder.ToString ();
}
```

Comment: That "result" looks like it's base64-encoded

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your result is base64-encoded. [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a way of taking a byte array and turning it into human-readable characters.

Your code tries to take these raw bytes and cast them to chars, but not all byte values are valid printable characters: some are control characters, some can't be printed, etc.

Instead, let's turn the hex string into a byte array, and then turn that byte array into a base64 string.

```
string input = "01BB92E7F716F55B144768FCB2EA40187AE6CF6B2E52A64F7331D0539507441F7D770112510D679F0B310116B0D709E049A19467672FFA532A7C30DFB72";
byte[] bytes = new byte[input.Length / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    bytes[i] = byte.Parse(input.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}

string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

This results in:

> AbuS5/cW9VsUR2j8supAGHrmz2suUqZPczHQU5UHRB99dwESUQ1nnwsxARaw1wngSaGUZ2cv+lMqfDDftw==

[See it running here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dUScX8).